# How to get password with Facebook login plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to let people sign up with their Facebook account.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=215838765244788&
         redirect_uri=http://localhost&
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email,password"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
 </iframe>
```

How can i get password with the facebook login plugin if its not possible then how can use the login plugin for logging?

Comment: sorry for my bad english i dont know if i explained it good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using facebook login button in your application/site you need not worry about the user login. Facebook API takes care of all the authentication. You should not implement your own login box when using facebook login. 
          It works like when user first visits your site/app facebook checks for the login status and on click of the facebook login button user will be redirected to the facebook login page which is structured as per the device user is using. After authentication the facebook redirects user to your domain/app. 
        So in short you need not worry about how the authentication is done when using fb login.

Thanks

Comment: so people use login plugin together with sign up plugin when they click login button i check database that if the user r already in my database so i let log them in?

Comment: As per my understanding you are maintaining the database of users for your app/site. If this is the case then why do you wish to use facebook authentication. You can authenticate users on your behalf only. Then you can give an option to user to login in to your site using facebook or login using your sites authentication(this approach is used by many sites now a days,i.e providing multiple authentication options to users).You can use Facebook login as the only authentication mechanism for your site,then you won't have to implement database of users for authentication.

Comment: thanks for your explanation im still confused shouldnt i save register information (email,name etc.) to my database ?

Comment: Hi, if you are implementing only Facebook login to authenticate user, and also you want to save user information for future use,you definitely can get Facebook userid of the visitor and his/her mail id etc and store in your database. Thats up to you how you want to use this information of user. Next thing is if you are using your own authentication method or not? If using then user will obviously be required to signup to your site and you can easily store his info.